# Ansible - The PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) module is required

Tags: ansible, pymysql

My ansible code looks like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Install python
  apt:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    update-cache: yes
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - python
    - python-dev

- name: Install pymysql
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    executable: pip
    state: present
  with_items:
    - PyMySQL==0.7.11
    - MySQL-python

- name: Install mysql and deps
  apt:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    update-cache: yes
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - mysql-server
    - libmysqlclient-dev
    - python-mysqldb
    - python-pip

- name: Create DB
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    collation: utf8_general_ci
    encoding: utf8
  with_items: "{{ database_names }}"
```

When I run it, I get the error,

> failed: [xxxxx] (item=xxxxx) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "xxxxx", "msg": "The PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) module is required."}

But from my sensible code you see I installed both PyMySQL and MySQL-python prior to calling `mysql_db`. Also, from ansible runtime log, I see both PyMySQL and MySQL-python got installed successfully:

```
TASK [mysql : Install python] **************************************************
ok: [aquila] => (item=python)
ok: [aquila] => (item=python-dev)

TASK [mysql : Install pymysql] *************************************************
ok: [aquila] => (item=PyMySQL==0.7.11)
ok: [aquila] => (item=MySQL-python)

TASK [mysql : Install mysql and deps] ******************************************
ok: [aquila] => (item=mysql-server)
ok: [aquila] => (item=libmysqlclient-dev)
ok: [aquila] => (item=python-mysqldb)
ok: [aquila] => (item=python-pip)

TASK [mysql : Create DB] ************************************************
failed: [xxxxx] (item=xxxxx) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "aquila", "msg": "The PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) module is required."}
```

Why `mysql-db` is not getting the PyMySQL or MySQL-python module?

Comment: 1) You don't need to install both libs. Just install the one needed for your python version. 2) You can find plenty of similar problems and solutions by researching existing questions in the search bar above. The source of the problem is almost always the same: you are installing the lib in a different version of python than the one Ansible is currently using on the target. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Comment: So you assume that ansible is randomly changing python versions  between tasks of a playbook? If so than I think we are better going back to the good old manual days. I run into this problem wenn trying to create a playbook that only connects to localhost. So there has to be the same environment....

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error on CentOS 7, but on Ubuntu 20.04 this works for me:

```
- name: Install pip
  apt:
    name: python3-pip
    state: present

- name: Install PyMySQL
  pip:
    name: pymysql
    state: present
```

UPD: Here's a solution on CentOS 7:

```
- name: Install MySQL-python
  yum:
    name:
      - python3-pip
      - MySQL-python
```